# Probability: mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm working on showing that: If A and B are mutually exclusive events, and $P(B) >0 $, show that

$P(A|A \cup B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)} $

My take:

1. We know that if A and B are mutually exclusive events, then $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

2.We know that $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

My idea is to combine these two facts somehow, but it doesen't really add up, and I'm stuck now. Would really appreciate help.

Comment: $A \cap (A\cup B)=A$ since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: In "2."  should be $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$.

Comment: @zkutch I've edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

regardless that A and B are joint or disjoint,

$$A\cap(A\cup B)=A$$

you can verify it simply with a Venn's Diagram. This is also self evident observing that

$$A \subseteq (A\cup B)$$